# Сброс значения сессионной переменной при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: php, сессия

Есть простая форма c использованием `AJAX` - 2 текстовых поля и кнопка для отправки значений:

```
<form method="post" name="chooseProduct" class="choose-product-form">
    <input type="text" name="product" placeholder="Название продукта">
    <input type="text" name="portion" placeholder="Размер порции">
    <input type="button" value="Добавить" id="addProduct">
</form>
```

После каждого нажатия на кнопку значения ( float ) суммируются с предыдущими и все это сохраняется в сессионную переменную.

Можно ли средствами `PHP` очищать сессионную переменную при обновлении (перезагрузке) страницы ?

Comment: `unset($_SESSION['someValue'])` ?

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой ответ: можно.

Answer (score 1):

Пара вариантов:

1. По умолчанию очищайте значение переменной сессии. Добавьте в свой Ajax запрос параметр-флаг говорящий о том, что очищать переменную не нужно.
2. Добавьте в событие загрузки страницы вызов php скрипта для очистки переменной сессии.

```php
if(isset($_REQUEST["cleanup"])){

     if(isset($_SESSION["sum"]))
     $_SESSION["sum"] = 0;

}
```